# Changing the link in a Feature box to an external link

Tags: features, navigation

I am a Drupal beginner working with an already created site.

That said, I have been trying for days to change the text within the feature box to an external link. Currently, all of the text in the feature box links when clicked to an internal site path. I understand how to change the text to incorporate a link, but I want to continue to have all of the text in the box clickable as an external link, including the Title.

In the Links To dropdown of the Menu Attributes area I have it set to -None- but it still is redirecting to the Home page. I don't know how to add an external link in this dropdown, or using path aliases (I do understand nodes and path aliases for *internal* links). I have also tried Primary and Secondary links. Is there any super simple way to redirect feature box text to an external link?

Sorry for the long description, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Can you be more specific what you mean by the feature box? Which theme is your site using? It sounds like you are working directly in the Drupal menu system which usually presumes internal links.